# how to connect to cloud DB in eclipse, giving java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, cloud

i am trying to create a database connection , but database is not in my localhost, so i provided the IP instead of localhost in

```
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(conStr, user, pass);
```

where

```
constr="jdbc:mysql://54.86.136.55/oms"
```

but its giving an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'ac4773IU'@'125.63.90.34' (using password: NO)
```

but i login with the same user name and password

Comment: using password NO?that seems to be you trying to log without password .does your pass="";?

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha no i have provided the correct password in pass.. its not blank

Comment: i think its some DB access issue